# How to View several columns conditioned on the value in one of them?

Tags: r

In the following code below, i look over three variables in a dataset. However, I would like to look over the three variable when the year column is equal to 72. Is there a way to do it by using the View function?

```
library(plm)
data("Cigar")

View(Cigar[, c("year","price", "sales")])
```

Comment: `View(Cigar[Cigar$year == 72, c("year","price", "sales")])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. One way is to use `subset()` with `select`. You don't need to quote column names.

For example:

```
View(subset(Cigar, select = c(year, price, sales), year == 72))
```

In R version 4.1.0 or newer you can also use the `|>` pipe :

```
Cigar |> 
subset(Cigar, select = c(year, price, sales), year == 72) |> 
View()
```